# tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender delegates show warning

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In my delegate it shows warning

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
{
    return YES;
}
```

Warning:Conflicting return type in implementation of 'tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:': 'void' vs 'BOOL'(aka.'signed char')

Guide me to solve this warning

Answer (score 1):

Make the return type `void`, as required by the protocol:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender
```

You may have confused the `tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` method which returns `void`, with the `tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` method, which returns `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1):

That method has no return type. It's the `tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:` delegate method with a `BOOL` return type.